# Create a static library from iOS Application project

Tags: android, ios, xcode, eclipse, static-libraries

Is there a way to compile an iOS Application Project in Xcode as a static library like in Eclipse? In Eclipse if I want to use an Android Application Project as a Library for other projects I only need to check  "is library" in its properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to change the setup of an existing project.  Start a new Xcode Project (File->New->Project) and choose iOS->Framework & Library->Cocoa Touch Static Library, and then copy over your files.